# VSTO is not getting installed by Visual Studio installer

Tags: c#, outlook, installation, vsto

I have to deploy VSTO Outlook add-in with Visual Studio installer with custom actions. Installer is performing custom actions while installation but VSTO is not getting installed to Outlook. I had to install VSTO manfully from application folder. Kindly help me to install VSTO on one click.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A rough guess is that it is already installed.  Look in c:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly\gac_msil

Comment: VSTO is not installed to GAC as well..

Answer (score 0):

**I don't know if you already solved this or not, but i'm just gonna share what I did. I followed this two article, they are showing step-by-step what they did and it pretty much similar to my environment. I don't know if it similar to yours but both of these works for me.**

http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/create-excel-2007-vsto-add-in-msi-installation.aspx

http://www.jakesee.com/2013/02/how-to-create-visual-studio-setup-project-for-vsto-add-in/

---

BTW, when doing the registry key part, beware of typing "LoadBehaviour" instead of "LoadBehavior". I did typo this part and spent hours looking for solution, but it was just a typo problem.

**The correct should be "LoadBehavior" without "u" in middle of "o" and "r".**

---

Plus, make sure you do both registry 32-bit and 64-bit, because I got problem that the installation is complete but the add-in wasn't even in my Excel. Then I found out that I just did the installation setup for 32-bit instead of 64-bit (where my pc use 64-bit).

**You can refer this:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/registry-entries-for-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019